# Why does CountA produce an extra row

Tags: excel, vba

My code produces an extra row, whenever I fill any data at row 4 column T.
If I leave row 4 column T empty, it will display data at row 5.

```
Sub All_N()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Sheets("sum").Activate
    Sheets("sum").Range("A5:T1048576").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Sheets("sum").Range("A5").Select

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "sum" Then
            cont1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("T3:T1048576")) + 2

            For a = 2 To cont1
                If ws.Cells(a, 20) = "N" Then
                    b = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("sum").Range("T3:T1048576")) + 5
                    Sheets("sum").Cells(b, 1) = ws.Cells(a, 1)
                    Sheets("sum").Cells(b, 2) = ws.Cells(a, 2)
                    Sheets("sum").Cells(b, 18) = ws.Cells(a, 18)
                    Sheets("sum").Cells(b, 19) = ws.Cells(a, 19)
                    Sheets("sum").Cells(b, 20) = ws.Cells(a, 20)
                End If
            Next a
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to loop over **all used rows** in all your sheets
and then fill in the **next empty row** in your "sum" sheet.

To find the last used row in column "T",
you may use `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row`

```
Option Explicit

Sub All_N()
    Dim wsSum As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim a As Long, b As Long

    Set wsSum = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sum")
    With wsSum
        .Range("A5:T" & .Rows.Count).ClearContents
        b = 5
        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Name <> "sum" Then
                For a = 2 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row
                    If ws.Cells(a, "T") = "N" Then
                        .Cells(b, 1) = ws.Cells(a, 1)
                        .Cells(b, 2) = ws.Cells(a, 2)
                        .Cells(b, 18) = ws.Cells(a, 18)
                        .Cells(b, 19) = ws.Cells(a, 19)
                        .Cells(b, 20) = ws.Cells(a, 20)
                        b = b + 1
                    End If
                Next a
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

It is not necessary to `Select` or `Activate` anything, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/10908769).

Comment: > thanks for your input , if i would like to adjust the data display to start from row 5 , how can i do so , thanks again

Comment: Now I start with b = 5 and increment it as necessary. If it works for you, please consider to mark it as answer as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). If not, don't hesitate to comment here again.

Comment: when i click the button the initial data display showing at row 2 but when i click again the button the data showing at row 5 , the data showing at row 2 and row 5 is duplicate , so still got some minor correction needed, please help

Comment: Of course :) The code deletes everything starting in row 5 in sheet "sum", and then adds row-by-row starting in row 5. So everything above row 5 is old untouched data. So please decide: Where to start in "sum" (actually row 5) and where to start in all other sheets (actually row 2).

Comment: The sheet sum will display the result from row 5 onward but however data countstart from row 2 at others tab , as u can see my data at others tab data entry is start from row 2 onward , hope my explaination is not confuse

Comment: Then everything is fine now, as I did it so :) Just adapt your first 4 rows in "sum" manually once. They will remain untouched by my code.

Comment: Do u mean I need manually delete the row 2,3 data for the first time I click the button ? Anywhere to avoid that ?

Comment: Anyway to avoid the first initial data result showing at row 2 for the first time I click the button ?

Comment: I edited my code 3 hours ago directly after your first comment. Since then my code DOES NOT TOUCH "sum" ROWS 1 to 4.